# Keeping TortoiseSVN & NetBeans IDE in Sync at all times

Tags: svn, netbeans, synchronization, tortoisesvn

I am using NetBeans with integrated subversion control.

If I make commits, adds, etc. through TortoiseSVN, NetBeans doesn't recognize those actions.

Obviously though if I make changes through NetBeans my local folders are synced respectively.

I've tried restarting the IDE, refreshing folders, etc. but NetBeans still doesn't reflect the updates. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: version of NetBeans? maybe it's EA release or beta?

Comment: 7.1...I'm guessing this is not normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it supports what you're looking for without some sort of user interaction.

What I do is right-click the Project -> Subversion -> Show Changes. The panel that opens has a Refresh button that rescans svn. This has worked for me for the last several versions as well as different versions of SVN (1.6 vs massive 1.7 changes).

You could also try the official forums and see if you can get an official response: [forums.netbeans.org](http://forums.netbeans.org).

**Update**

Just remembered something. Are you using SVN 1.6 or 1.7? Last I heard Netbeans doesn't natively support SVN 1.7. See [this page](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Subversion1_7) for more information.