# Is there anything that TortoiseSVN can do that can't be done through Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, tortoisesvn

I was reading that the [Netbeans IDE has built-in Subversion support](http://dev.umpirsky.com/eclipse-vs-netbeans-for-php-development/#attachment_394). I've also seen [a reference to using Netbeans and Subversion together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233864/keeping-tortoisesvn-netbeans-ide-in-sync-at-all-times). But I've been a long-time Tortoise user, and I know it can slow down the Windows shell. Is it redundant to install TortoiseSVN if you are using NetBeans? **Is there anything that TortoiseSVN can do that can't be done through Netbeans?**

Comment: Asking same question in NetBeans forum: http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=142468#142468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a thread in the NetBeans user forums with the same question at http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=142473#142473.

The [first respondent](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-142473.html#142473) indicates that NetBeans subversion plugin does not allow for "ignoring" added project files, and that there may be other SVN tasks which can not be completed through NetBeans but can be done through TortoiseSVN.